# DDD: Trying to understand functionality between boundary contexts

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am currently trying to understand DDD and have a similar application to the following.  Let's assume that I have a shopping cart application with the following items:

Shopping Cart (BC denotes boundary contexts)
Shopper (BC)
    - Person (VO)
Product (BC)
    - Product (Entity)
Billing Information (BC)
    - Address (VO)
Cart (BC)
    - Cart Entity
    - LineItem (Product FK, Address VO)  (Entity)
    - Shopper FK
    - Billing FK

A shopper visits a site and browses products to purchase.  As the shopper selects a product, it gets added to the cart along with options such as quantity to purchase, etc.   When the shopper is ready to checkout click a link to review the items in their cart, where they can remove any items they do not want.    After this step, they can continue to checkout where they can either enter or select a credit card and an address to send the cart items to.  The person's credit card is billed and the cart and items are displayed in a queue to the department that will fulfill the order.

Would I be right in assuming that this is the proper boundary context breakdown?

If there is a one to many relationship between shopper and cart, how should this be represented between the two aggregate boundaries or would this violate a rule?

Considering that they are in different contexts, should the shopper repository call the cart repository to populate its list of carts that are associated with the shopper?

Also, since it seems natural for the line item to exist within the Cart boundary, should the cart repository be responsible for crud operations on the line items as well as populating the list of line items associated with the cart?

Comment: Not a downvoter but could you please explain why the application is divided into these bounded contexts? What is the pros and cons?

Comment: This is an example.  One of my questions was whether or not I was correct in breaking down my contexts in this manner.

Comment: Yes, but context map decision depends on use cases and architectural facts. You have to provided these information.

Comment: Usually, two aggregates in different bounded context do not reference to each other. I think the bounded context is too fine-grained. In my experience, shopping cart itself is just one bounded context.

Comment: @user1790300 Have you confused Bounded Contexts with Aggregate Roots?

Comment: With the hierarchy mentioned above, what would be the optimal bounded contexts and aggregate roots?

Comment: Like @Hippoom mentions, it's hard to know precisely without knowing more about the domain you're working in.  But if you substituted (BC) for (AR) in your original post, it would look a lot more typical of a DDD project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your bounded contexts are far too granular and that you may have mixed bounded contexts (BC) with aggregate roots (AR).

I do not know your domain, but bounded contexts shouldn't align 1 to 1 with aggregate roots, they should align 1 to 1 with sub-domains (in an optimal scenario).

Aggregate roots are transactionnal boundaries and responsible to protect true invariants, while bounded contexts are basically a mean to avoid terms overloading by splitting the problem space into smaller contexts with their own ubiquitous language.

For instance, a **Product** in the **Shopping** bounded context is potentially different from a **Product** in the **Shipping** context. E.g. in the **Shopping** context, you could be interested about the review score of a product but you wouldn't care about this in the **Shipping** context. On the other hand, in the **Shipping** context you might want to know how a product should be safely packaged, but that information might not be important in the **Shopping** context.

If you didin't divide your problem space into bounded contexts you would end up with the Product term being overloaded and it's concrete model implementation (e.g the `Product` class) would be huge, hard to grasp and hard to maintain.

I cannot tell you what should be your bounded contexts, but I feel pretty confident in saying they are wrong and I would strongly advise you to read more about [bounded contexts](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) and [aggregate roots](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/).